# phpStorm command line command points to wrong project

Tags: laravel, composer-php, phpstorm

i'm quite new with laravel and composer. I've made a project previously and that works like a expected. Now i've started a brand new project 'bloemenn' in phpstorm choose composer project for type and installed laravel. When i run the project i see the welcome page of laravel. So far so good

But now i'm trying to make a controller with the command line tool but every command i execute points to my very first directory project i ever made.
So the controls are made but in the wrong directory.

so when i execute following command in phpstorm for project bloemenn:

**Artisan make:controller indexController**

i get following result:

**/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.7/bin/php /Users/u-123/project-test/laravel/artisan make: indexController**

so the controller is made in project laravel instead of directory of project bloemenn

Anyone have any idea how i can fix this, i have this issue for every new composer project i start up?

Comment: `php artisan make:controller indexController` ? Are you executing it in Terminal, in `vagrant ssh` -> in directory path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok,

found it myself

under preferences->Tools->Command Line Tools Support can you specify witch to uses
mine all pointed to my first project